# Multilevel Sum up (related child levels to its parent level) without macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula

in one of my workbooks ı will have *dynamic* Bill of Material like (BoM) structure. Table will be dynamic so indenture levels can be change in time.

constants are:

- only childs can take value and parents will get their value from
  their child.
- Parent value = sum of its children value

Aim is:

- any parent labeled row is the sum of its children's values. level (n+1) are child of level n 
  for example

  ```
  1       {30+50}         parent
  2       {10+10+10}      parent
  3       10              child
  3       10              child
  3       10              child
  2       50              parent
  ```

what I tried:

- I could achieve parent/child labeling. assuming Level heading is in
  cell A1 then related formula is:

  `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A3));IF(A3>A2;"parent";"child");IF(A46=A45;"child";"parent"))`
- searched the web especially SO however couldn't find a beneficial
  example
- After searching a lot, I concluded that it can be achieved with `offset`,`match`,`index`,`row` and usage of array formulas may be however ı couldn't achieve

These dynamic structure has lots of rows so it will be really beneficial to me to make it auto. I can't run a macro (not allowed)

I think solution will be a long command sentence and If someone can help with some explanations also (logic, a very brief aim of the substep maybe) it'll be very appreciated

I like here cause I learn a lot (rather than getting a ready solution until next same case)

I studied with the example data below. **(edit: "Manually Calculated Vals" column added to clarify what is being asked for. Actually that column is what I need done auto by excel)**

**edit2: there was an error in "Manually Calculated Vals" column. Thanks to XORLX. I corrected it.**

regards

```
Level   Value   Parent/Child    Manually Calculated Vals
0               parent          1815
1               parent          668
2               parent          110
3       19      child           
3       91      child           
2               parent          330
3               parent          200
4       40      child           
4       79      child           
4       81      child           
3       60      child           
3       42      child           
3       28      child           
2       3       child           
2       35      child           
2               parent          137
3               parent          113
4       46      child           
4       67      child           
3       24      child           
2       53      child           
1               parent          1147
2               parent          195
3       96      child           
3       99      child           
2               parent          325
3               parent          142
4       59      child           
4       83      child           
3       40      child           
3       79      child           
3       64      child           
2               parent          240
3               parent          151
4       80      child           
4       71      child           
3       89      child           
2               parent          157
3       57      child           
3       100     child           
2               parent          169
3       91      child           
3       20      child           
3       58      child           
2       61      child
```

Comment: In all that explanation you don't appear to have given the most important piece of information, i.e. what your expected results for that dataset are, and why.

Comment: sorry, our internet was down temporarily, I will edit question. briefly, level4s sum is equals to their parent level3, level3s sum is equals to their parent level2 and so on. Level 0 is equal to the sum of all level1s. Parent labeled rows need proper sum operation.

Comment: Thanks. Are your results supposed to be entered in the large table you give, in a fourth column to the right of the Parent/Child data? If so, could you manually add in all of your expected results, just so that it's clear what is being asked for?

Comment: @XORLX hi, I am not a native english speaker. if I understood correct your comment, I added calculated values column.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. And your English is fine! Can you just explain some of your calculated values? For example, why is the value in row 8 119? This is for the the 2 level 4 children in rows 9 and 10, but why isn't the level 4 child in row 11 also included in this calculation?

Comment: Oh I am so sorry, row11 must be included to the sum also. so sorry, I immediately will correct my fault by editing the q again.

Comment: @XORLX i corrected the error. thanks for your remark.

Comment: Thanks. And shouldn't the entry in the very last row in the Value column be blank? Which would also mean that your results for rows 2 and 23 would change.

Comment: actually that row is special I added intentionally, it's a parent since its level is numerically lower than the 1 upper row's level (it's 3). However it'a childless parent also. I added those parent/child formulation if those could help me visually to produce some other formulas. Since your style of thinking requires a value also for the very last row, I am adding it to the q also. So in the future people won't think that there are some gaps in the whole logic. thank you so much  by the way until now, I took a lot time from you.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand this last criterion. Is this something that could occur more than once in your data, not just for the very last row? I have a solution which works if, as I said, that final entry is blank, though if that is not what is required then you would probably need to produce a new dataset with more examples of this criterion with some explanations.

Comment: i am very happy that you had a solution works IF the final entry is BLANK. actually my logic was saying that final enntry MUST be blank since it has already a value in 2nd column. I (mistakenly) understood that you have a solution in your mind which needs it unblank. So no problem exist by the time being. I will edit the q for the last time (last row'll be BLANK again as it was) and wait for your solution. I hope to learn your logic also from your answer. thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure we're understanding each other. The final entry in the second column needs to be blank, not 61 as it currently is.

Comment: @XORLX unfortunately, last column is absolutely valid for my case. It has no children to sum up so it has a value itself in 2nd column. Actually there is no difference with the last row and the 1st row from top that has (level2 , value = 3) combination. (and the row just below it with(level2 , value = 35) combination.) The only difference is their labels (child or parent) SO for now I think that  last row's label must also be CHILD. (if it was not at last row but at some middle point, then it was very simple to figure out. Being "last row" confused me) I updated the label.

Comment: Ah, if it's a child then that works. Will post solution now.

Comment: thanks to you and God :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is in A1:C46 (with headers in row 1), put this **array formula**** in D2:

```
=IF(C2="child","",SUM(B3:INDEX(B3:B$46,LOOKUP(10^10,MATCH({6,1},SEARCH("T",(A3:A$46<=A2)&"T"),0))-1)))
```

Copy down as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: I entered as an array formula however it pop-ups error message says "not trying to type formula?" I will add the picture of popup to my question temporarily

Comment: my fault: I forgot to replace `,` with `;`

Comment: yes it works superb however in my suitable time I will study my lesson to understand the way your code works, thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome! If you ever need an explanation just reply in this thread.